# fill listbox when I select another listbox

Tags: google-apps-script

sorry for my code, i try simplify in this example for my explication.
the information of a listbox depend of I select in other listBox, but it can´t work.
sorry for my bad english.

here I create my form;

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Request Form');
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel().setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center").setWidth("900px");

      var lreason = app.createLabel('Select reason :');
      var listreason= app.createListBox().setName("listreason").addItem("").addItem("SALUD").addItem("MOTIVO PERSONAL");
      var lfactor = app.createLabel('Select Factor :');
      var listfactor= app.createListBox().setName("listfactor").addItem("Select reason first").setId(listfactor);


  var handlerr = app.createServerValueChangeHandler('factors');
  handlerr.addCallbackElement(flow);
  listreason.addChangeHandler(handlerr);   
  var test1 = app.createLabel('nada'); 

  var gridd = app.createGrid(4,5);

      gridd.setWidget(2,0,lreason)
      .setWidget(2,1,listreason)
      .setWidget(2,3,lfactor)
      .setWidget(2,4,listfactor)
      .setWidget(3,0,test1.setId('test1'));

    flow.add(gridd);
  app.add(flow);  
  return app;  
}
```

//////////////////here create the function for fill the other listBox

```
function factors(e){
var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 

var var1=e.parameter.listreason;
app.getElementById('test1').setText(var1);  

switch (var1) {

    case "SALUD":

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1pBayt_tB84E3wKhb-H5tVZJolx04F-Uq-Iom8O3KVHs');
var list = ss.getSheetByName('Salud');

 var lastRow = list.getLastRow();

var templ = app.createListBox();  
var values = list.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).getValues();
for (var i in values){
templ.addItem(values[i][0].toString());
}
app.getElementById('listfactor').addItem(templ);

  break;

    case "MOTIVO ESCOLAR":

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1pBayt_tB84E3wKhb-H5tVZJolx04F-Uq-Iom8O3KVHs');
var list = ss.getSheetByName('MotivoEscolar');

 var lastRow = list.getLastRow();
var templ = app.createListBox();  

var values = list.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).getValues();
for (var i in values){
templ.addItem(values[i][0].toString());
}
app.getElementById('listfactor').addItem(templ);
  break;

    default: 

app.getElementById('test1').setText("empty");  

    break

}
    return app; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code you use is wrong (see comments in code):

```
for (var i in values){
templ.addItem(values[i][0].toString());
}
app.getElementById('listfactor').addItem(templ);// you can not add a litBox as an item in another listBox
```

You should simply add one item after the other in the loop... move your code like this :

```
for (var i in values){
//templ.addItem(values[i][0].toString()); // this new list box is useless since you populate the existing one
app.getElementById('listfactor').addItem(values[i][0].toString());
}
```